# The diagonals of a parallelogram are given by the vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, area

The diagonals of a parallelograms are given by the vectors $3\vec {i} + \vec {j} + 2\vec {k}$ and $\vec {i} - 3\vec {j} + 4\vec {k}$. Find the area of the parallelogram.

My Attempt:
Let $\vec {d_1}=3\vec {i} + \vec {j} + 2\vec {k}$ and $\vec {d_2}=\vec {i} - 3\vec {j} + 4\vec {k}$ be two diagonals represented in vector form. 
How do I get the base and altitude to find the area of parallelogram?

Comment: Your attempt consists of giving the two vectors names. Can you do a bit more than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec a=3\vec {i} + \vec {j} + 2\vec {k}$

$\vec b=\vec {i} - 3\vec {j} + 4\vec {k}$ be the diagonals of a parallelogram, then its vector area $=\dfrac12(\vec a\times \vec b)$

Here $\vec a\times \vec b=\begin{vmatrix} \vec {i} & \vec {j} & \vec {k} \\ 3 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & -3 & 4 \end{vmatrix}$
$$=\vec {i}(4-6)-\vec {j}(12+2)+\vec {k}(-9-1)$$
$$=-2\vec {i}-14\vec {j}-10\vec {k}$$
$$=2(-\vec {i}-7\vec {j}-5\vec {k})$$
Therefor, vector area of the parallelogram is $$=\frac12[2(-\vec {i}-7\vec {j}-5\vec {k})]$$
$$-\vec {i}-7\vec {j}-5\vec {k}$$
Area of the parallelogram is $$=|-\vec {i}-7\vec {j}-5\vec {k}|$$
$$=\sqrt{1+49+25}=\sqrt{75}=5\sqrt{3}\mbox{ sq. units}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$A=\frac{ef}{2}\sin(\alpha)$$ this is $$A=\left|\frac{e\times f}{2}\right|$$
the cr4oss product of your two vectors gives $$[10,-10,-10]$$ therefore the area is given by $$A=5\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: What's that formula for? where and How to use it?

Comment: use that $$|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=ab\sin(\angle{\vec{a},\vec{b}})$$

Answer (score 0):

Use

> $$A= |\frac{1}{2} \vec{d_1 }× \vec{d_2}|$$